# remove elements in list (contrary to filter)

Tags: haskell

Hello im trying to remove elements from a list which applies to my function as such:
removeBy even [1..10] → [1,3,5,7,9]  or 
removeBy (=='a' ) ['b' , 'a' ,'c' ] → "bc"

using high order functions like map, foldl, foldr, and filter
what i did is

```
removeBy :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [b]
removeBy function list = map function list
```

when i try to run example 1 with even i get

```
Variable not in scope: removeBy :: (a0 -> Bool) -> [a1] -> t
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: How exactly are you trying to run it? What commands do you type in? Where?

Answer (score 8):

You can just do `filter (not . condition) list` — that is, negate the condition, i.e. filter all the values which do `not` satisfy the condition. So e.g. your `removeBy (=='a')` would be the same as `filter (not . (=='a'))` — or even simpler, `filter (/='a')`.

As for why your attempted implementation didn’t work: `map function list` simply applies `function` to every element of `list`, and so cannot add or remove any elements.

Comment: Exactly! just using a filter and the negation of a condition on the given list :D